# Java Mission Control from JDK 1.8.0_161 frozen upon startup on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, jmc

I'm trying to launch Java Mission Control as provided in the JDK 1.8.0_161 on Mac OS X High Sierra (10.13.2, with Supplemental Update of January 2018) and the JMC application is frozen, i.e. I'm unable to browse in the JVM Browser panel.

As I've other former JDK installed, therefore I've checked JMC with the following versions with success:

- 1.8.0_121
- 1.8.0_144
- 1.8.0_151

So the problem is very specific to the JDK 1.8.0_161.

(To see your JDKs, run the command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`)

(To run a former JMC, i.e. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jmc`)

As a side verification, I've run the JMC of the JDK 1.8.0_161 on Windows 10 with success.

So do you experience the same issue ?

Is there some settings to tweak to have it working ?
(E.g. would it be an issue related to Mac OS X Gatekeeper !?)

And how to report it to Oracle properly ... I've searched their bug database without success, and when I try to submit a bug, I cannot figure which would be the right subcategory (c.f. https://bugreport.java.com/submit_intro.do), as JMC is not listed in the TOOLS section ... Any advice !?

Comment: Works with JMC 6 that comes with JDK 10.0.1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is unfortunately a bug that we recently discovered, caused by incompatibilities between old Eclipse/SWT versions and new fixes done in JDK 8u152 (backported from JDK 9).

Workaround is to run older version of JDK 8, or the latest version of JDK 7 (which includes the same version of JMC). JDK 9 also works, with the new JMC 6 included.

(Oracle Internal) bug reference: JMC-5139

Comment: the bug still has on java version "1.8.0_162"

Comment: @klara this is even not working in JDK 8u152 as well.

Comment: This issue started in JDK 8u152, I'm not aware of any work to fix this for coming JDK 8 update releases.

Comment: The bug still here on 1.8.0_171

Comment: Do you know which versions of SWT are affected by this bug? We face a similar issue in a local application, indeed using an "old version" of SWT, but can't find a corresponding issue on SWT's bug tracker...

Comment: Ok, forget it, I've found the answer by myself. Eclipse MAT is getting the same issue with SWT 3.104. The latest release of Eclipse (photon, released in June 2018) bundles with SWT 3.107, and doesn't have the issue. Some people from the MAT community has demonstrated that the issue can be resolved simply by replacing SWT with a newer version: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1090889/

Comment: plus 1 on the information, minus 1 on the workaround path.

Comment: Awful - what kind of testing do you guys do?

Answer (score 47):

There's a workaround for this, as mentioned by @jwatkins in a comment.

1. Download the swt cocoa jar from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.eclipse.platform%20AND%20a:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64&core=gav).
2. Go to JDKs jmc path (You can find this path by right-clicking on jmc icon in the dock -> Options -> Show in Finder, Then right click on App -> Show Package Contents).

   - For example:  `cd
     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol`
3. Back up exisiting jar using `sudo mv
   plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.1.v20140903-1947.jar
   ../`
4. Copy downloaded zip's swt.jar using `sudo cp ~/Downloads/swt.jar
   plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.1.v20140903-1947.jar`
5. Restart `jmc`

**NOTE**: Remember! your new copied jar file's name should be exactly as the old one(it uses OSGi bundles.info to load jars)

Comment: I have jdk 1.8.0_202, it does not have "org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.1.v20140903-1947.jar"   ⇒  ls plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx*
plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.nl_ja_4.4.0.v20140623020002.jar        plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.nl_ja_4.4.0.v20140623020002.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.nl_zh_4.4.0.v20140623020002.jar        plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.nl_zh_4.4.0.v20140623020002.jar

Comment: The plugins seems to have version #s that cause the start to fail when you copy in a replacement jar

Comment: The link in step one does return but all of the mirrors I've tried 404.  Used this instead: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.eclipse.platform%20AND%20a:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64&core=gav and downloaded the lastest (3.109 in my case).  Worked!

Comment: This worked for me on 1.8.0_202 after replacing org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.1.v20140903-1947.jar

Comment: JMC is now working but I am getting this exception when loading a JFR file
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData
 at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.flushCache(FillLayout.java:176)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:870)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.requestLayout(Control.java:2847)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.destroyItem(CTabFolder.java:816)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem.dispose(CTabItem.java:130)

Comment: I fixed the exception with version 3.108.0 of SWT. The latest versions were buggy for me.

Comment: That issue might be due to api changes

Comment: Worked for me jdk v1.8.0_211. Used the 3.108.0 version of the jar. Thanks @RasikaPerera

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and if you don't mind using eclipse, you can install this plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-mission-control.

But as [Klara's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48403970/1972564) I eventually managed to run Java Mission Control (not the very newest version though but it still unblock me without big workarround):

1. Download [an older JDK version](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html?printOnly=1) (I took the `Java SE Development Kit 8u91`)
2. I placed it in my /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines repository. **I did not change my environment variables** as I want to keep using a newer version.
3. I launched the app placed in jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/Java Mission Control.app

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue according to the official website. And they don't seem to be doing anything about it since Jan 2018.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jmc55-release-notes-2412446.html#known-iss

That mentions three solutions but I followed @Rasika Perera answer to fix this issue on JDK 1.8.0_202

Or you can download this latest version of JDK Mission Control which works on MacOS
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/products-jmc7-downloads.html